# Create Array of Strings from Group Contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsfilemanager, nsbundle

I have 3 xml files in a group folder within my project's supporting files. I'm trying to create an array that contains the filenames, as strings, for each file in the group's folder.

Example...Group Folder Named XLMS

```
XMLS
   one.xml
   two.xml
   three.xml
```

The way I have shown, only works if the files are in an actual folder (blue). How may I do the same for a group folder (yellowish)? Please help, thanks.

```
viewDidLoad

NSMutableString* bundlePath = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:4];

[bundlePath appendString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];

[bundlePath appendString:@"/XMLS"];

NSArray *stringArray  = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundlePath error:nil];

[stringArray description];
```

Comment: The yellow folder is a virtual group managed by Xcode, it has nothing to do with the directory hierarchy in main bundle.

Comment: Is there an approach to get the contents of the group? Please make a suggestion that I can try.

Comment: Yes, They are all in your bundle path. :)

Comment: Groups don't exist in the final app bundle. Groups are simply a way to organize files in your project, not in the built app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder references will create a directory in the bundle, allowing you to figure out the contents. By using Groups, you cannot do this. If you insist on using the a Group, an option is to create a manifest that contains the names of the file you want.

Note this is more error prone because you need to make sure the manifest contains the right filenames (i.e. if you change a filename, you'll need to make sure to update the manifest) AND you will also need to load the manifest first. Why don't you want to use Folder References in this case? If you make the manifest a plist you can automagically load it as an array doing something like:

```
NSMutableArray *stringArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:manifestPath];
```

Comment: Just going with a Folder Reference is proving to be the best way. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to keep the files inside a folder reference (blue folder). The code provided is the same as in my question. It is good for creating an array of strings that match the filenames inside a folder reference.

```
viewDidLoad

NSMutableString* bundlePath = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:4];

[bundlePath appendString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];

[bundlePath appendString:@"/XMLS"];

NSArray *stringArray  = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundlePath error:nil];

[stringArray description];
```